# How to extract html links from html file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, html

Can anyone help me by explaining how to extract urls/links from HTML File in C#

Comment: This ought to be a dupe.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack

Answer (score 11):

look at [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); 
doc.Load("file.htm");  
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")) 
{
    HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
    yourList.Add(att.Value)  
}  
doc.Save("file.htm");
```

Comment: Do this. Parsing HTML with RegEx can be a very tedious task, Html Agility Pack will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Agreed, HTML Agility pack is the way to go.

Comment: One up for the Html Agility pack!

Answer (score 2):

Use HTMLAgility Pack...

```
    private List<string> ParseLinks(string html)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument(); 
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
        return nodes == null ? new List<string>() : nodes.ToList().ConvertAll(r => r.Attributes.ToList().ConvertAll(i => i.Value)).SelectMany(j => j).ToList();
    }
```

It works for me.

Answer (score -2):

You can use an HTQL COM object and query the page using query: 
<a>:href

```
HTQLCOMLib.HtqlControl h = new HTQLCOMLib.HtqlControl();
string page = "<html><body><a href='test1.html'>test1</a><a href='test2.html'>test2</a> </body></html>";
h.setSourceData(page, page.Length);
h.setQuery("<a>: href ");
for (h.moveFirst(); 0 == h.isEOF(); h.moveNext() )
{
     MessageBox.Show(h.getValueByIndex(1));
}
```

It will show messages of:

test1.html

test2.html