# Using HTMLAgility Pack to Extract Links

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Consider this simplest piece of code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace WebScraper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml("http://www.google.com");

            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This effectively doesnt do anything at all, and is copied/inspired from various other StackOverflow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336088/how-to-extract-html-links-from-html-file-in-c). 
When compiling this, there is a runtime error which says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." highlighting the foreach line.

I can't understand, why the environment has become irritable to this humble,innocent and useless piece of code.

I would also like to know, does HTMLAgilityPack accept HTML classes as nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to load html from the web, you need to use the `HtmlWeb` object:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc =web.Load(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

`LoadHtml` takes a string of actual HTML as an argument.  You can pass Load a Stream from [`WebResponse.GetResponseStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) instead.

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create( "http://www.google.com" );
Stream s = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
doc.Load(s);
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt foresee this.